# Hide class element based on ID data of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

**HTML**

```
<a class="us-btn-style_6" id="post-102" href="#">Real Estate</span></a>
<article class="w-grid-item post-102" data-id="102"></article>
```

**jQuery function**

```
$('.w-grid-item').hide();
var class1 = ".";
var post_class = "";
$('.us-btn-style_6').click(function(){
    post_class = $(this).data('id')
    post_class = class1 + post_class
    $(post_class).show();
});
```

There are 7 buttons with 7 corresponding `<articles>`. The button's `ID` has the same data as the article's `class`. What needs to happen, when the button is clicked the `<article>` needs to be simply show up. In the jQuery I try to take the ID data to show the corresponding class. What goes wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `post_class = $(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @freedomn-m you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `.data` method, there should be a corresponding `data-` prefixed attribute, in this case `data-id`:

```
<a class="us-btn-style_6" data-id="post-102" href="#">Real Estate</a>
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$('.w-grid-item').hide();
var class1 = ".";
var post_class = "";
$('.us-btn-style_6').click(function(){
    post_class = $(this).data('id')
    post_class = class1 + post_class
    $(post_class).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="us-btn-style_6" data-id="post-102" href="#">Real Estate</a>
<article class="w-grid-item post-102">
Test
</article>
```

Comment: Yes you're right; I shouldn't have used `.data('id')`. But I think a better solution is to change `data` into `attr` so `.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

You put a data-id the wrong element. It would need to be on the item you clicked, not the element you want to show.

I would clean it up like this:

```js
$("[data-toggles]").on("click", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var selector = $(this).data("toggles");
  $(".post").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="us-btn-style_6" data-toggles=".post-102" href="#">Real Estate</span></a>
<a class="us-btn-style_6" data-toggles=".post-103" href="#">Foo Estate</span></a>


<article class="w-grid-item post post-102">X</article>
<article class="w-grid-item post post-103">Y1</article>
<article class="w-grid-item post post-103">Y2</article>
```

Comment: Yes you're right; I shouldn't have used `.data('id')`. But I think a better solution is to change `data` into `attr`; `.attr('id')`.